# Remover item selecionado bottombar (Lib Roughike)

Tags: android, android-layout, app, navigation-drawer, library

Tenho um aplicativo que utiliza o NavigationView e o BottomBar, estou com uma dificuldade pra remover a seleção do item do bootombar quando seleciono um item do navigationView, estou utilizando a Library do Roughike https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar.

Eu tentei usar:

```
// Remove item selected BottomBar *** Problem here ***
    public void rmSelectBottom() {
        bottomBar.getCurrentTab().clearFocus();
        bottomBar.getCurrentTab().setSelected(false);
    }
```

***Mas não obtive o sucesso***

Código completo

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);

        toolbar.setTitle("Title");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);


        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

            }
        });

//BottomBar
        bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(0);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

                Fragment fragment = null;
                Class fragmentClass = null;

                rmSelectNavigation();

                switch (tabId) {
                    case R.id.tab_home:
                        fragmentClass = TabHomeFragment.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_notas:
                        fragmentClass = TabGradesFragment.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_aval:
                        fragmentClass = TabAvaliationsFragment.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_faltas:
                        fragmentClass = TabAbsencesFragment.class;
                        break;
                }

                try {
                    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

            }
        });

    }

// NavigationView
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;

        rmSelectBottom();

        if (id == R.id.nav_notification) {
            fragmentClass = NavIncidentsFragment.class;
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_task) {
            fragmentClass = NavTasksFragment.class;
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_content) {
            fragmentClass = NavContentFragment.class;
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_financial) {
            fragmentClass = NavFinancialFragment.class;
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_promotion) {
            fragmentClass = NavPromotionsFragment.class;
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_config) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (id != R.id.nav_config) {
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

// Remove item selected NavigationView
    public void rmSelectNavigation() {
        int size = navigationView.getMenu().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
        }
    }
// Remove item selected BottomBar *** Problem here ***
    public void rmSelectBottom() {
        bottomBar.getCurrentTab().clearFocus();
        bottomBar.getCurrentTab().setSelected(false);
    }
```

**Existe algum outro método específico para remover o item selecionado?**

Segue a imagem com o exemplo do problema:

<kbd>[image: Na imagem eu seleciono o item **TAREFAS** do NavigationView e o item **NOTAS** no BottomBar manteve selecionado.]</kbd>

Comment: Kowal, tenho quase certeza que não é possível remover a seleção de uma tab usando essa lib, acho que não é um caso de uso dela se parar pra pensar. Seguindo os specs do Material Design, não tem nenhuma menção a Bottom Bar sem ter elemento não selecionado. Será que talvez não seja melhor tirar o Bottom Bar das telas do NavigationView que não possuem items no BottomBar?

Comment: No App do Google+ tem um bom exemplo, se você clicar no item Eventos do NavigationView ele irá manter o bottombar e todos os itens será desmarcado.

Comment: É, realmente tem razão, vi aqui. Minha sugestão é experimentar a `BottomNavigationView` que está embutida na Design Support Library, acho que a partir da versão 25. Como nunca experimentei, não tenho certeza se ele disponibiliza uma API pra isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita procura sem encontrar uma solução para o problema com a <strike>Library do Roughike</strike>, resolvi seguir a sugestão do @Wakim e utilizei o BottomNavigationView, que esta na Design Support Library 25.

Solução:
*Quando clico em um item do NavigationView eu chamo um método que percorre os itens do BottomBarNavigationView e da um **setChecked(false)***

```
int size = bottomBar.getMenu().size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    bottomBar.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
}
```